# How to read file with Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Is it possible for Numba to read a file?

I tried using the standard Numpy method save and load and got a not-supported error.

Is there any other format Numba can handle? If not, what should one do when one needs to read from a file and still wants to use the power of Numba?

Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
a = np.random.randn(400, 400)
np.save('test', a)
@njit
def f():
    a = np.load('test.npy')
    return a
b = f()
> TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
> Unknown attribute 'load' of type Module(<module 'numpy'
```

Comment: Read the file using Numpy, then create a Numba object from the Numpy object?

Comment: Read the array outside of the compiled function, or compile in object mode (jit instead njit). There is nothing to speed up in this function, except faster hardware.

Answer (score 4):

You will gain no benefit from reading the file within numba and `np.load` is not supported (see [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html) for the complete list of supported functions). Numba functions should, to get full benefit of the jit, just operate on scalars and arrays. Read the data in during your setup and then pass the arrays contained in the file into the numba-jitted function.

Comment: This is not ideal as that means I need to re-organise all my code as I was reading the array "deep" into the jitted routines.

Comment: @gota -- you don't really have much of a choice, unfortunately, as the function is not supported in `nopython` mode. The only workaround I can think of is writing some C-code to read in the data, wrap it using cffi (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#cffi) and then in the C-code, copy the data into a pre-allocated numpy array that numba understands. I'm not sure what the performance characteristics are going to be though, and it's going to add a build step that might not be desirable and is certainly more complex.