# Passing parameter values from file to numba class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I'm building a `numba` simulation class in python, and I'd like to pass to it some parameter values from earlier simulation which are stored on file. There are lots of parameter values saved on file, so they're in a file which I'm accessing using `pandas`.

Unfortunately, trying to use `pandas` within `numba` throws an error. Specifically, it seems that numba is unhappy that I'm calling pandas inside of it and assigning values it's not sure how to type them. (Note: if I split those chained pandas calls into multiple lines, it identifies the `read_feather` line as the culprit):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from numba import jitclass, float32, int32
from pandas import read_feather

import os
PARAM_FILE = SOME_PATH_ON_MY_MACHINE

import numba
print(numba.__version__)

@jitclass(
    spec=OrderedDict(
        a=float32,
        b=float32,
    )
)
class MyParameters:
    def __init__(self,) -> None:
        simulated_parameters = read_feather(PARAM_FILE).sample(1, axis=0).squeeze().to_dict()
        self.a = simulated_parameters["a"]
        self.b = simulated_parameters["a"]

demo_bug = MyParameters()

### OUTPUT
0.45.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe-numba.py", line 42, in <module>
    demo_bug = MyParameters()
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/jitclass/base.py", line 126, in __call__
    return cls._ctor(*bind.args[1:], **bind.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 376, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 343, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'read_feather': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "mwe-numba.py", line 32:
    def __init__(self,) -> None:
        simulated_parameters = read_feather(PARAM_FILE).sample(1, axis=0).squeeze().to_dict()
        ^

[1] During: resolving callee type: jitclass.MyParameters#10116c320<a:float32,b:float32,c:float32,tstar:int32,cstar:float32,loc:float32,scale:float32,shape:float32>
[2] During: typing of call at <string> (3)

[3] During: resolving callee type: jitclass.MyParameters#10116c320<a:float32,b:float32,c:float32,tstar:int32,cstar:float32,loc:float32,scale:float32,shape:float32>
[4] During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

Trying to be clever, I decided to create another class to hold the parameter information and then put the `read_feather` in there. However, that didn't work either

```
class MyParameters:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        simulated_parameters = read_feather(PARAM_FILE).sample(1, axis=0).squeeze().to_dict()
        self.a = simulated_parameters["a"]
        self.b = simulated_parameters["a"]

@jitclass(
  OrderedDict(
    a=float32,
    b=float32,
  )
)
class MyModel:
  def __init__(self, param: MyParameters) -> None:
    self.a = param.a
    self.b = param.b

my_param = MyParameters()
print("That was no problem")
my_model = MyModel(param=my_param)

### OUTPUT
0.45.1
That was no problem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "also-error.py", line 40, in <module>
    my_model = MyModel(param=my_param)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/jitclass/base.py", line 126, in __call__
    return cls._ctor(*bind.args[1:], **bind.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 376, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 343, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/deeprl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
[1] During: typing of argument at <string> (3)

File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.MyParameters'>

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

Is there anything I can do to put this code within numba? I can think of workarounds but they're all a bit clunky.

Comment: As far as I know Numba doesn't support pandas at the moment. See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html and the next page(s).

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911063/how-to-read-file-with-numba?rq=1) highlights that `numba` is best used for scalar & vector operations and not data wrangling, so does not support `pandas`.

The other issue is you are tying to pass a `dict` as essentially the `kwargs` in your class `__init__`, this [issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2916) on Github explains why this is a problem. This  generic argument handling would need to be done in Python mode (for example, popping items out of the kwargs) inside a nopython mode function, this functionality does not exist at this point.

This means when you are parsing in the `OrderedDict` you would essentially have to tell `numba` to expect a python `dict` which would not really make sense, however `numba` has `Dict` [functionality](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-dict) as of `0.43`. [SO post example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078628/using-dictionaries-with-numba-njit-function).

However, if you try do this it will result in the below error:

*Load modules*

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from numba import jitclass
from numba import types 
from numba.typed import Dict
```

```
@jitclass( 
    OrderedDict([ 
        ('params', Dict.empty( 
            key_type=types.unicode_type,
            value_type=types.float64,
        )) 
     ]) 
) 
class MyModel: 
    def __init__(self, params): 
        self.a = params["a"] 
        self.b = params["b"] 

TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got DictType[unicode_type,float64]({})
```

Essentially you have to tell `numba` what `args` to expect, I would in your case do the below:

Assume you have used `read_feather`, resulting in the below `dict`:

```
simulated_parameters = {"a" : 2.0, "b" : 5.0}
```

Now initialise the `numba` class:

```
@jitclass( 
    OrderedDict([ 
        ('a', types.float32), 
        ('b', types.float32) 
    ]) 
)
class MyModel: 
    def __init__(self, a, b): 
        self.a = a 
        self.b = b

foo = MyModel(simulated_parameters["a"], simulated_parameters["b"])
```

Comment: This makes sense -- your points w/r/t the general utility of numba are helpful.

However, I'd like to get the `read_feather` within the `__init__` method of my class somehow -- either by putting it there directly (which probably doesn't make sense - ie example 1), or by having the `__init__` method call another class (example 2) that calls `read_feather`. In my example this is just one of many modules in the code, so it would be nice for it to initialize automatically.

Comment: It's not the end of the world b/c at the moment I have a `make_model` function that does the `read_feather` to get the model, initializes the model with those parameters, and returns the model, but it's a little bit clunky and if I could call `Model()` explicitly that would be cleaner.

Comment: Yeah it's tough with `numba` as it's really just intended for the numerical operations of your model. You could put `read_feather` in your `__init__` method however you would have to then remove the `@jitclass` decorator...

Comment: Sounds like messing with my current setup is unlikely to be helpful. I posted on numba forums as well, will update here if anyone has a better solution.